# ASP.Net MVC: Entity Selection in View without using dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-ajax

I have an EditTask View for editing the following properties for a Task that I am modeling.

> [Task Name]
>
> [Project Name]
>
> [Assigned Employee]

Task Name and Project Name are just simple text boxes.

I want Assigned Employee to be a selection from all the available Employee's currently in the database.  Dropdownlist is not really an ideal option because there could be hundreds if not more possible employees.

I'm thinking a link to show a select employee grid listing in either a popup or another page where filtering can take place (b/c employee has other properties such as Dept) and the selection is made and the EditTask view is updated would be ideal but not sure.  I'm new to ASP.NET MVC so I'm a little lost on where to start to implement this.

What is the best way to handle this UI scenario in ASP.net MVC?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Ajax functionality to show a list of filtered users. You can also follow the approach that you mentioned above like a separate filter view or a popup.

I would prefer the Ajax approach.

You can use JQuery to do this kind of things very easily. You can refer to [this](http://www.pnpguidance.net/post/jQueryAutoCompleteASPNETMVCFramework.aspx) link for more information